# pushing carousel when video playing

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" id="homecarousel" data-ride="carousel" style="margin-left: -170px;">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <iframe src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxaSjrWnEuDWVWZ3dDNBbHVPa1E/preview" class="center-block" style="width: 50%; height: 400px;"></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <iframe src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxaSjrWnEuDWNHFUYXpLR19hN00/preview" class="center-block" style="width: 50%; height: 400px;"></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev" style="background-image: none;">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next" style="background-image: none;">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

How can I push the carousel when the video is playing?

Comment: You can look for events for iframe.

Comment: @Hardik Vaghani yes...

Comment: i am using boostrap carousel